# Show that there exist $A>0$ (not depend on $m$) such that $|u_{m}|>A$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $(u_{m})_{m≥1}$ be a strictely positive and convergent sequence. Then show that there exist $A>0$ (not depend on $m$) such that $$|u_{m}|>A$$ for all $m≥1$.

I think to exploite the fact that **any convergent sequence is bounded (both above and below)**. However without any success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $(u_n)$ is convergent, then it's bounded. Let denote $M=\inf |x_n|$. Then, $A=M-1$ work.

Comment: @ Rick: But I require that $A>0$.

Comment: Such an $A$ doesn't exists. What do you think about $x_n=\frac{1}{n}$ ? @DER